# How to fetch array in correct order

Tags: php, arrays

How to  fetch array in correct order ?

I am printing a array but it is not fetching in correct order.

I want that each track value contain array of date and array of 
  number respectively. please give a solution .Any help would be
  highly appreciated.

My code for fetch array are:

```
  <?php
        foreach($posts as $post)            
        {
            $array['track_value'][] = $post->track_value;
            $array['track_value']['date'][] = $post->date;
            $array['track_value']['num'][] = $post->num; 
         }  
  ?>
```

From this i am getting wrong value like these:

```
  <?php
       Array (
     [track_value] => Array
         (
              [0] => mobile
              [date] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => 2015-08-23
                      [1] => 2015-08-24
                      [2] => 2015-08-23
                     [3] => 2015-08-24
                      [4] => 2015-08-22
                      [5] => 2015-08-23
                      [6] => 2015-08-24
             )

              [num] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => 1
                      [1] => 1
                      [2] => 1
                      [3] => 2
                      [4] => 1
                      [5] => 1
                      [6] => 1
                  )

              [1] => mobile
              [2] => laptop
              [3] => laptop
              [4] => pc
              [5] => pc
              [6] => pc
          )

  )
  ?>
```

The output should be like:

```
  <?php
  Array (
      [track_value] => Array
          (
              [0] => mobile
              Array
              (
                  [date] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => 2015-08-23
                         [1] => 2015-08-24
                      )

                  [num] => Array
                      (
                   [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                 )
              )

              [1] => laptop
              Array
              (
                  [date] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => 2015-08-23
                     [1] => 2015-08-24
                      )

                  [num] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => 1
                          [1] => 2
                      )
              )    
              [2] => pc
              Array
              (
                  [date] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => 2015-08-23
                          [1] => 2015-08-24
                          [2] => 2015-08-23
                      )

                  [num] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => 1
                          [1] => 1
                         [2] => 1
                      )
              )
          )

  )
 ?>
```

Comment: You can not create an array like that, as everything in an array is a key-value-pair. If you don't specify a key, it will use its own index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this will help you on the way:

```
foreach($posts as $post)            
{
    $array['track_value'][$post->track_value]['date'][] = $post->date;
    $array['track_value'][$post->track_value]['num'][] = $post->num;
}
```

This will give you an output like:

```
Array(

    'track_value' => Array(

        'mobile' => Array(

            'date' => Array(

                0 => '2015-08-25',
                1 => '2015'08'26',

            ),

            'num' => Array(

                0 => 1337,
                1 => 13337,

            ),
        ),
        'pc' => ...
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $tracks = [];

  foreach($posts as $k1 as $v1) {

         if (is_array($value)){

           foreach ($value as $k2 => $v2) {

              $tracks[$k1][$k2] = $v2;
           }
         }

         $tracks[$k1] = $v1;
  }
```

Comment: Has has multiple dates within a `[$key]` so it will override the previous stored one in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $arr = [];

  foreach($posts as $key => $val)
   $arr['track_value'][$val->track_value][] = ['date' => $val->date, 'num' => $val->num];
  }

  print_r($arr);
```